# what is the similar triangles argument?

Tags: geometry, computer-science, 3d

I’m reading a textbook on 3D graphics math. It’s describing how to model a pinhole camera, using a film plane at z = 1. However, the book then says this:

> Given a point p in the scene with eye coordinates [x,y,z,1] it is easy
>   enough to see (say, **using a similar triangles argument**) that
>   the ray from p to the origin hits the plane at:
>
> x_n = -(x/z)
>
> y_n = -(y/z)

my question is, what do they mean by “using the similar triangles argument?” I’m aware similar triangles are ones with the same shape, but I don’t know what the “argument” they refer to here is, nor how it demonstrates the normals are negative [x or y] over z. I’m not very well versed in math, so apologies if this seems like a silly thing to not know.

Update: people asked for the associated diagram, here it is, or at least the closest one to the text above:
[image]

Comment: If you can [edit] the question to include an image showing the point and the plane and $p$ we might be able to see which triangles are involved. (The image, not a link, please.)

Comment: I guess he means the classical argument on proportionality. Suppose that two triangles are congruent, that is, they have the same shape but not necessarily the same size. Pick two sides $A$ and $B$ from the first one and $A'$ and $B'$ the corresponding sides of the second one. Then $\dfrac{|A|}{|B|}=\dfrac{|A'|}{|B'|}$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the length of the side.

Comment: They mean use, say, SAS similarity or some other postulate.

Comment: It's not very clear but I think it is using the ratio of 1/z  on the the x and y coordinates (similar triangles made by rays of light from the point x,y,z and the origin to the pinhole and projected through onto the plate) as they appear on the plate and the negative sign is maybe due to the inversion of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the below annotated image with only the images that matter will help you understand better

[This is a view of the triangle formed by point P on yz plane w.r.t pinhole (origin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Eka.png)

I considered a point on the yz plane, x = 0 to make it easier

Let P=[0,y,z] and it's reflection on the z=-1 plane be Q[0,y_n,-1]

You can verify that the triangles on the opposite sides of the y=0 plane in the above picture are similar triangles. So, from the rule of equal ratios of sides,

```
z/z_n = y/y_n

Since z_n is on z=-1 plane, the distance is always "1" from origin
z/1 = y/y_n

y_n = (y/z)  (Here y_n is the distance of Y from origin. Not the actual coordinate)
```

The similar triangles rule is used to derive the value of `y_n` w.r.t `y,z` which are known coordinates. But the negativity comes from the fact that they are on the opposite sides of the y=0 plane

i.e. coordinate(y_n) = -(y/z)

You can do a similar setup with xz plane to derive x_n = -(x/z)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).